# Mapping the event position to the text position in non text-fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to map an event such as a click-event on this element

```
<div>Just normal text</div>
```

to the position in the contained text ( "You just clicked the 6th character", when hitting the 'n' )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any pretty way of achieving that but I got a solution that would work, although it's ugly.

You could wrap each letter of your `div` text in a lets say `span` element and add unique identifiers for each letter. Then you'd hook up event handlers for those `span` elements, not the whole div and based on the span id you could tell which character was that.

This whole thing can be done in JS but as I said that's not the ideal solution for sure.

Here's the example (I've added a `test` id to the div so I could find it easier).

```
var letters = $('#test').text();
var spans = '';
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    spans += '<span id="id' + i + '">' + letters[i] + '<span>';
}
$('#test').html(spans);

$('span[id^=id]').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked char: ' + (Number($(this).attr('id').substring(2)) + 1));
    return false;
});
```

You can also give it a try on my [demo](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/stackoverflow/clicked_character.html).

Comment: I would like to add, that the splitting into spans should be done by jquery and not on the actual html

Comment: That's what I've written in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such; I guess you would have to split each character into a `<span>` element, either on server side or using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky way that could possibly be made to work: it involves temporarily making the document editable and examining the selection. It should work in Firefox 3+, IE 6+, recent Safari and Chrome.

As it stands, there are some problems I can see:

- The results in IE are different to other browsers: IE counts all characters in the whole containing *element* up until the caret while other browsers give an offset within the containing *text node*, but you could work round this;
- A border appears round the current element in some browsers
- Doesn't work in Opera or Firefox 2, and leaves document editable
- Possibility of other UI glitches: it's a nasty hack.

Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mouseDownEl;

    document.onmousedown = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        if (evt.srcElement || !("contentEditable" in el)) {
            document.designMode = "on";
        } else {
            el.contentEditable = "true";
        }

        mouseDownEl = el;
    };

    document.onclick = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        if (el == mouseDownEl) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var caretPos, range;
                if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
                    caretPos = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
                } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
                    range = document.body.createTextRange();
                    range.moveToElementText(el);
                    range.collapse();
                    range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", document.selection.createRange());
                    caretPos = range.text.length;
                }

                if (el.contentEditable == "true") {
                    el.contentEditable = "false";
                } else {
                    document.designMode = "off";
                }
                alert(caretPos);
            }, 1);
        } else {
            if (mouseDownEl.contentEditable == "true") {
                mouseDownEl.contentEditable = "false";
            } else {
                document.designMode = "off";
            }
        }
        mouseDownEl = null;
    };
};
```